# Using apply to send multiple arguments to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, signalr

I'm working on a javascript client in angular that uses SignalR to communicate with a backend server. The basic idea is that you can do remote procedure calls on the server from the client and vice versa. I have an appropriate abstraction for calling a server method that takes no parameters as follows:

```
myInvoke: function (methodName, callback) {
            proxy.invoke(methodName)
                .done(function (result) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
        }
```

The important part being `proxy.invoke(methodName)` which takes the name of the server method to call as a string.

proxy also allows passing multiple arguments to invoke. Some examples from [SignalR documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#callserver):

```
// one parameter 
contosoChatHubProxy.invoke('newContosoChatMessage', { UserName: userName, Message: message}) ...

// two parameters
contosoChatHubProxy.invoke('NewContosoChatMessage', userName, message) ...
```

What I'd like to accomplish is something more like this where args is any number of arguments that should be forwarded on to the hub:

```
myInvoke: function (methodName, args, callback) {
            proxy.invoke(methodName, args)...
```

I've been reading about the apply method but my javascript is pretty weak and I haven't been able to come up with a working implementation.

Comment: The args is just a JS object so pass an object in and default to an empty object and you should be in business. The only reason you'd need to use apply is if you want to pass some set of default params.

Comment: @GordonBockus I don't understand how that will work if I pass 10 arguments into invoke then. How does it know what to do with all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignore my previous comment.  I misread the SignalR doc you included.  Basically I was assuming you could always pass a single object parameter.  It does look like you can accomplish what you want by doing

See this jsbin for how to use apply to pass the arguments from the current function to the invoke function.

http://jsbin.com/juqanigulo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Hey had to make a couple minor changes to your code to get it to work. callback didn't need to be a part of args as it didn't need to be passed on to the SignalR server, its used to act on the value returned from the RPC invocation. Also I had to do apply (proxy, args) instead of (null, args) but after that it does what I want! Thanks a lot :)